# Ejecutar método al cargar la pagina Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Tengo la función `getSession` en el elemento `methods` de Vuejs y necesito ejecutarla al momento de cargar, ya sea la pagina o la instancia Vue

Este es el código Javascript

```
new Vue ({
    el:'#homeApp',
    data:{
        session:{}
    },
    methods:{
        getSession: function () {
            var vm = this;
            axios.post('php/session/session.php',this.createdFormData(this.session))
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var vm = this;
                if (response.data.state == true ){

                } else {

                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        createdFormData: function (postData){
            var formDa = new FormData();
            for(var key in postData){
                formDa.append(key, postData[key]);
            }
            return formDa;
        }
    }
});
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Puedo hacerlo desde el documento Javascript? o ¿Debo hacerlo desde el documento html con alguna directiva?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo ideal sería que lo hicieras dentro de [mounted()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) que se invocará como su nombre lo dice al momento de montar la instancia en el DOM con los elementos HTML cargados. Nos puede ser muy útil para inicializar librerías externas en algunos casos.

Aunque sí su método no depende de algún elemento del DOM y no renderizará datos sobre este podría hacerse dentro del método `created()` sin problemas.

```
new Vue ({
    el:'#homeApp',
    data:{
        session:{}
    },
    mounted(){
     // invocar los métodos
     this.getSession();
    },
    methods:{
    ....
```

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre created() y mounted()?

Básicamente con `created` no tendrás acceso a los elementos del DOM, con `mounted` sí,

**Ejm**, $el retorna el `div` con el id #app

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  mounted(){
     console.log('Mounted ' + this.$el);
  },
  created(){
    console.log('Created ' + this.$el);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

</div>
```

> Sería bueno a futuro para sesiones, manejaras con un mixin o quizá con vuex . *( ya que será algo que necesites en más de un lugar de su aplicación Vue)*

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre created() y mounted()?

Comment: @EmilianoPamont en que en created no tienes acceso a elementos del DOM, en mounted sí.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer eso con `created()`

```
methods:{
   getSession(){
   }
},
    created: function(){
        this.getSession()
    }
```

> Created, ejecutara el codigo justo después de que toda la instancia de
> Vue que declaraste sea cargada

Fuente de referencia: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

```
Mounted => El DOM esta completamente cargado asi como los componentes 
Created => El DOM  y los componentes aun no han sido cargados
```

Comment: puse una breve explicación @EmilianoPamont